# Trouble printing a table with a specific form

Tags: python, arrays, printing

I am working on programming the Simplex method (to solve LPP problems) in Python and I am basically done. I am now working on the aesthetic part and I am having some problems. A simplex table is a table as follows:

[This a sample of a Simplex Method Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kW9WV.png)

Currently, I have produced the following code: The information on the table is right but I can't figure a way to produce the cool lines and to put the basic variables on the left, and all the variables on top. Please note that I have a function that gives me the indexes of the basic variables (i.e., according to the picture above, I have a function that gives me the indexes 3,2,5) and the top part I believe would be pretty simple (since we print every variable from 1 to the length of the table). I am also having trouble on printing float numbers in the table with only 2 decimals.

```
def show_tableau(tableau: float):
basicIds = get_basic_indexes(tableau)
print('---------------------------------')
for i in range(len(tableau)):
    if i == len(tableau)-1:
        print('---------------------------------')
    for j in range(len(tableau[0])):
         print(f"{tableau[i][j]}\t", end = "")
    print('')
print('')
print('Jb = {', [value+1 for value in basicIds], '}\n')
```

This code produces the following output: (values don't matter)

[My code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rq1uq.png)

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Could u give an example of how the tableau list is structured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To round, your values to a two digits float just change this line

```
print(f"{tableau[i][j]}\t", end = "")
```

to this

```
print(f"{round(tableau[i][j],2)}\t", end = "")
```

Comment: Answering your comment now: the tableau list is a bidimensional array, by looking at my output, each line (let i be this line) is the array corresponding to tableau[i]. Thanks for your help (the decimal round worked)!

Comment: I updated the code the "}" was in the wrong spot now it should work :) Thy for the clarification.